# Is it right way to update List View custom adapter in onProgressUpdate in Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, custom-adapter

I have Created Model and Calling Asynchronous task in MainActivity onCreate function to update adapter. It is working fine but i have doubt whether can i update adapter in Asynchronous  onProgressupdate function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to update the adapter in postExecute of the AsyncTask.

Comment: I don't want wait till all items loads. Why I am updating adapter in on progress update means I want to display item in listview one by one.

Comment: Ok, onProgressUpdate is called on the UI main thread, you can try to update the adapter anyway